# Vectorise an imported variable in R

Tags: r

I have imported a CSV file to R but now I would like to extract a variable into a vector and analyse it separately. Could you please tell me how I could do that?

I know that the `summary()` function gives a rough idea but I would like to learn more.

I apologise if this is a trivial question but I have watched a number of tutorial videos and have not seen that anywhere.

Comment: You need to read [An Introduction to R](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.pdf).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have use the `read.csv()` or the `read.table()` function to import your data in R. (You can have help directly in R with `?` e.g. `?read.csv`

So normally, you have a data.frame. And if you check the [documentation](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/data.frame.html) the data.frame is described as a   "[...]tightly coupled collections of variables which share many of the properties of matrices and of lists[...]"

So basically you can already handle your data as vector.

A quick research on SO gave back this two posts among others:

- [Converting a dataframe to a vector (by rows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2545228/converting-a-dataframe-to-a-vector-by-rows) and
- [Extract Column from data.frame as a Vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3922461/extract-column-from-data-frame-as-a-vector)

And I am sure they are more relevant ones. Try some good tutorials on R (videos are not so formative in this case). 
There is a ton of good ones on the Internet, e.g:
* http://www.introductoryr.co.uk/R_Resources_for_Beginners.html (which lists some) 
or 
* http://tryr.codeschool.com/

Anyways, one way to deal with your csv would be:

```
#import the data to R as a data.frame
mydata = read.csv(file="SomeFile.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",", 
quote = "\"",dec = ".", fill = TRUE, comment.char = "")

#extract a column to a vector
firstColumn = mydata$col1 # extract the column named "col1" of mydata to a vector
#This previous line is equivalent to:
firstColumn = mydata[,"col1"]

#extract a row to a vector
firstline = mydata[1,] #extract the first row of mydata to a vector
```

Edit: In some cases[1], you might need to coerce the data in a vector by applying functions such as `as.numeric` or `as.character`:

```
firstline=as.numeric(mydata[1,])#extract the first row of mydata to a vector
#Note: the entire row *has to be* numeric or compatible with that class
```

[1] e.g. it happened to me when I wanted to extract a row of a data.frame inside a nested function

Answer (score 2):

Read data into data frame using read.csv. Get names of data frame. They should be the names of the CSV columns unless you've done something wrong. Use dollar-notation to get vectors by name. Try reading some tutorials instead of watching videos, then you can try stuff out.

```
d = read.csv("foo.csv")
names(d)
v = d$whatever # for example
hist(v) # for example
```

This is totally trivial stuff.

Comment: I did say it is probably trivial. Anyway, thank you.