# R Project Shiny Dynamic List Casting Issue

Tags: r, list, dynamic, shiny

I want the selectInput to show "Option1" and "Option2" not "1" and "2".

server.R

```
library(shiny)
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

 ## Uncomment one of the below options (single #)

  ## This option works but the data.frame only has 1 level, mine has 20 levels
  #my_list <-  as.character(c("Option1","Option2"))

  ## This option does not work and is as close as I can get to recreating my error
  #my_list <-  data.frame(c("Option1","Option2"))

  ## This option does not work as ds has Factor w/ 20 levels, 20 obs. of 1 variable
  #ds <- getData() 
  #ds <- data.frame(ds)
  #my_list <-  as.character(c(ds))


  output$my_list_select <- renderUI({
    selectInput(inputId = "select_input1", 
                label = h6("My List"), 
                choice = (my_list), 
                selected = 2)
  })
})
```

ui.R

```
library(shiny)
shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    mainPanel(
      fluidRow(        
        column(4,
               uiOutput("my_list_select")
        )))))
```

**Edition:**
At agstudy's suggestion I have rewritten the above so that it is as reproducible as possible ( I have a MYSQL query running on a local DB in `getData()` so what I can reproduce is limited).

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I guess, `getData` returns factors. Try `my_list <-  as.character(getData())`

Comment: Yes it does return factors. Using `as.character()` results in c(1, 2, ... 20) being the one and only choice.

Comment: I don't get your point. Very hard(waste of time) to help you without a reproducible example. Please, Add the result of `as.character(getData())` to your question.

Comment: Plase use 'dput(ds)' and show your data! Also the example is not a reproducible as we cannot see the actual source of error

Answer (score 0):

The solution was `my_list <-  as.vector(ds$symbol)`.

Found the answer thanks to [Extract Column from data.frame as a Vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3922461/extract-column-from-data-frame-as-a-vector)

Many many thanks for your help.